# Ext.getCmp with more then one id

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have following problem.
I have elements with id-s like element1, doNot, aNdSoOn

Now i can go and set the values from each of em like:

```
Ext.getCmp('element1').setValue('');
Ext.getCmp('doNot').setValue('');
```

But I want to avoid that. Can`t I somehow make it like in j-Query and separate the ids with coma or something like that???

Like

```
Ext.getCmp('element1, doNot, node').setValue('');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extjs do not offer facility like this but you can do this:

```
Ext.each(['element1', 'doNot'], function (id) {Ext.getCmp(id).setValue('')});
```